# Android app stops rendering code at a certain point

Tags: bug, android-app, code-formatting

If the code is too long it stops rendering the post. But I can scroll down to other answers

[image: missing content]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: HUAWEI
- Device Model: EVA-L09
- OS Version: 7.0 (C432B504)

Comment: Answering questions relating to mobile apps is apparently frowned upon.  Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320220/the-state-of-the-ios-and-android-apps-are-an-embarrassment-to-the-stack-overflow) question for further information on the state of the mobile app.