# Which technology/framework was used to develop the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app, stack-exchange-history

I am just curious to know - which technology/framework was used to develop the Stack Exchange mobile apps?

Is it native Android and native iOS (Swift/Objective-C) or hybrid frameworks ([React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native), etc.)?

Comment: Its not exhaustive but the about option on the android app has a listing of open source components that are used. Considering its two different developers, and apparently the ios version has slightly more features, chances are they're two separate, native codebases.

Answer (score 3):

I think the other answer is wrong; at least these parts

> Stack Exchange mobile apps are developed using any one of the many cross platform mobile app development tool.

> While the exact cross platform framework used could not be determined by this simple observation, but certainly the apps have not been developed using native development tools.

Stack Exchange's (former) Android developer [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232):

> I'll just say that there's a much, much bigger bang for the buck right now having a Java and an Objective-C developer writing C# than there is doing feature work on the app. I'm forever the optimist and would love to see us return to full app work some day, but I don't know when that day will be.

That pretty much proves there are two separate (native) codebases. Other evidence: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230639/295232) is stated that the Android app uses a [library](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/stacman-java) which is clearly Java. The app itself lists a lot of open source libraries ([e.g. Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)) which *may* be available for certain cross-site platforms but probably aren't.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience developing iOS apps. Based on my technical interpretation, from extensively using both the iOS and Android clients, Stack Exchange mobile apps are developed using any one of the many cross platform mobile app development tool.

Speaking of iOS client, it lets you [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204681) the current open post (on any of the SE site) to Safari running on a nearby Mac. This clearly indicates that the currently open view on iOS is running in within a Web view.

While the exact cross platform framework used could not be determined by this simple observation, but certainly the apps have not been developed using native development tools.

Another giveaway is the starkly similar interface across both iOS and Android clients, which is possible only when using a cross platform app development environment.

Comment: On the other hand, when they were in active development, they had different devs, and ios had a better feature set since it was developed longer, so I'm skeptical.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Any info on the current development status? I am especially curious about the iOS client.

Comment: I don't know. I wish I did, but I'm a regular user with moderator status, and don't get all the fun internal gossip. That said, the "about" page on the android client refers to the open source libraries they use. Maybe there's something similar in ios. As far as anyone knows, they basically are not going to do anything new, just fix bugs if needed.